# Is my "two room, two switch, four lights" diagram correct?

Tags: wiring, lighting

I have four lights altogether in two rooms that I want to power with one service. Each room has a SPST switch that will turn on two lighting fixtures in that room. I want to be able to turn the lights on in each room without having to worry if the other switch in the other room is on or not, so I do NOT want a three way switch setup.

I am also concerned with having to wire grounds in all my resistors as well. Do I need to, or is just wiring lead/neutrals going to work? I did not think it was necessary so my diagram does not have grounds included. However, my Romex is 14/2, so if I have to, the option is there.

I have been researching many videos/tutorials for this schematic, but can not find any that match what I am trying to do. I have also looked for some related answers here on Electrical Engineering, but could not find any that match. From what I know about parallel wiring, I believe I have this schematic correct, but I just need to make sure. Measure twice, cut once.

[image: Schematic]
[image: Schematic two, with ground]

Comment: You mentioned "resistors" in your question and comment. I assume you're not actually using resistors in your circuit, but are talking about the light fixtures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your diagram is correct. It will achieve what you described.

You should *always* connect the ground, it is a safety measure. While it may not appear to do anything during normal operation, it's presence covers many failure cases that have been discovered the hard way - death by electrocution, house burning down, etc.

You should also absolutely check your local electrical codes and regulations for how to correctly do an installation, there are many things that are not obvious or intuitive. In the USA, "NFPA 70" is the name of the code book. There are also many laws that cover who is allowed to do this kind of work, inspections, and etc.

Comment: Thank you I have already read my local building/electrical codes and have already received my permit to this work.

Comment: As a safety measure I will redraw my diagram to include grounds.

Comment: That probably would have got me a fail during inspection. haha

Comment: As far as my grounds are concerned. I imagine just splitting my grounds to the two rooms will do?

Comment: I imagine I will have to "pig tail" with wire nuts at each resistor?

Comment: Well, your codes will describe the accepted method to attach the grounds. For work I've done, if there's a metal box for switches or outlets, I would attach a ground pigtail to the box with a grounding screw, and then wire-nut it into the rest. But yes in general, you would connect the grounds together like you would do, separately, for the neutral wires.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot you have put my mind at ease.

Comment: I am just using plastic housings with plastic wall covers. The codes are pretty lenient here in South Carolina.

Comment: Plus, it is a garage, not a living space.

Comment: I have made my new diagram with grounds included. I believe this to be acceptable. It is post underneath the old one.

Comment: Looks good to me.